# Extract Date/time from string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID     RESULT
1      Pivot (Triage) Form Entered On:  12/30/2022 23:20 EST    Performed On:  12/30/2022 23:16 EST
```

I would like to extract both datetime variables so the new dataframe looks like this:

```
ID        END_TIME            START_TIME
1         12/30/2022 23:20    12/30/2022 23:16
```

I'm trying multiple methods but getting results where the `'END_TIME'` and `'START_TIME'` variables output is '`NA`'.

```
TEST['END_TIME']=TEST['RESULT'].str.extract("Entered On:  (\d+) EST")
TEST['START_TIME']=TEST['RESULT'].str.extract("Performed On:  (\d+) EST")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there always be 2 and only two timestamps, and using a more generic regex pattern, we can try:

```py
test[["END_TIME", "START_TIME"]] = test["RESULT"].str.extract(r'Entered On:\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) [A-Z]{3}\s+Performed On:\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) [A-Z]{3}')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WJxJWv/1) showing that the regex pattern and capture groups are working correctly.

Comment: This almost worked perfect, only one small issue - is that the new variables still had "EST". I fixed that with the following code: 'TEST['END_TIME']=TEST['END_TIME'].str.replace(r'EST', '')'
'TEST['START_TIME']=TEST['START_TIME'].str.replace(r'EST', '')'

Comment: @Raven I edited my answer so that it doesn't capture the time zones.

Answer (score 1):

**Test dataframe to start with :**

We build the following dataframe before applying regex function (I presume end date is always before start date) :

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

### We build dataframe test first ###
s = "Pivot (Triage) Form Entered On:  12/30/2022 23:20 EST    Performed On:  12/30/2022 23:16 EST"

df = pd.DataFrame([('1', s)], columns=['ID', 'RESULT'])

### ----------------------------- ###
```

```
  ID                                             RESULT
0  1  Pivot (Triage) Form Entered On:  12/30/2022 23...
```

You could use regex below in your code or use the following code (it's like best fits to you)
`regex = r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}'`

**With your script :**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

### We build dataframe test first ###
s = "Pivot (Triage) Form Entered On:  12/30/2022 23:20 EST    Performed On:  12/30/2022 23:16 EST"

df = pd.DataFrame([('1', s)], columns=['ID', 'RESULT'])

### ----------------------------- ###
# We define regex
regex = r'Form Entered On:  (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) EST'
df['END_TIME'] = df['RESULT'].str.extract(regex)
regex = r'Performed On:  (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) EST'
df['START_TIME'] = df['RESULT'].str.extract(regex)
```

**Another way :**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

### We build dataframe test first ###
s = "Pivot (Triage) Form Entered On:  12/30/2022 23:20 EST    Performed On:  12/30/2022 23:16 EST"

df = pd.DataFrame([('1', s)], columns=['ID', 'RESULT'])

### ----------------------------- ###
# We define regex
regex = r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'

df[['END_TIME', 'START_TIME']] = df.apply(lambda x: re.findall(regex, x.iloc[1]), axis=1).iloc[0]
```

**df['END_TIME'] :**

```
0    12/30/2022 23:20
Name: END_TIME, dtype: object
```

**df['START_TIME'] :**

```
0    12/30/2022 23:16
Name: START_TIME, dtype: object
```